# Adding and removing classes to current slide with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom-manipulation

Good evenening (at least where I live ;) )

I have a carousel set up. I would like to remove the class 'invisible' to the current slide.
Unfortunately, I'm a total noob when it comes to JQuery, and I'm having a really hard time understanding how to set this up properly.

This is the snippet

HTML

```js
const move = 600;

const margin_reset = (move * -1) + 'px'

setInterval(()=>{
  $("#inside-container").animate({
      marginLeft: (move * -2) +"px"
    }, 1800, function() {
      $(this).append( $(this).find('.items:first') )
        .css('margin-left', margin_reset);

        $('items.active').removeClass('active', 'invisible');
        $(this).addClass('active');
  }
  );

}, 4000)
```

```css
#outside-container{
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#inside-container{
  display: block;
  width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.items{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}
#item1{ background: green; }
#item2{ background: red; }
#item3{ background: blue; }
#item4{ background: yellow; }


.carousel-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}


.data-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 31%;
  left: 19%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="outside-container">
    <div id="inside-container" class="cf">
      <div class="items" id="item1">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{rio_de_janeiro.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{rio_de_janeiro.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items active" id="item2">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{new_york.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{new_york.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{new_york.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{new_york.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{new_york.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item3">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{london.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{london.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{london.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{london.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{london.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item4">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{sidney.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{sidney.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{sidney.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{sidney.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
       <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{sidney.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

#1 I don't even think that adding the 'active' class is needed in this case, but honestly I just threw it in there and see if it would help (bad idea I know, LOL)

#2 This should definitely be possible just by using plain JS, and if you feel more comfortable solving this using JS, feel totally free to do so. I'm not fixated on using JQuery

thank you very much in advance for any help :)

Comment: For the removing class part, removeClass requires multiple classes to be passed in an array. **$('items.active').removeClass(['active', 'invisible']);**

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```js
$('items.active').removeClass(['active', 'invisible']);
```

with regular JS:

```js
let element = $('items.active')[0];
//you can also use document.querySelector , document.getElementByID, etc.


element.classList.remove('active', 'invisible');
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but unfortunately I don't think I've explained myself good enough. I know how to add/remove classes with JS/JQ. What I'm haveing trouble with is to trace the current "slide" (items in the code) of my carousel, in order to remove the "invisible" class to the "data-div" that is shown in the frame

Answer (score 0):

Please see: https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-className

There are two methods:

> One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.

> An array of classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.

Method 1:

```js
const move = 600;

const margin_reset = (move * -1) + 'px'

setInterval(() => {
  $("#inside-container").animate({
    marginLeft: (move * -2) + "px"
  }, 1800, function() {
    $(this).append($(this).find('.items:first'))
      .css('margin-left', margin_reset);

    $('items.active').removeClass('active invisible');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}, 4000)
```

```css
#outside-container {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#inside-container {
  display: block;
  width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.items {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}

#item1 {
  background: green;
}

#item2 {
  background: red;
}

#item3 {
  background: blue;
}

#item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.carousel-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.data-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 31%;
  left: 19%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="outside-container">
    <div id="inside-container" class="cf">
      <div class="items" id="item1">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{rio_de_janeiro.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{rio_de_janeiro.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items active" id="item2">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{new_york.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{new_york.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{new_york.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{new_york.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{new_york.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item3">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{london.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{london.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{london.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{london.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{london.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item4">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{sidney.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{sidney.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{sidney.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{sidney.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{sidney.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Method 2:

```js
const move = 600;

const margin_reset = (move * -1) + 'px'

setInterval(() => {
  $("#inside-container").animate({
    marginLeft: (move * -2) + "px"
  }, 1800, function() {
    $(this).append($(this).find('.items:first'))
      .css('margin-left', margin_reset);

    $('items.active').removeClass(['active', 'invisible']);
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
}, 4000)
```

```css
#outside-container {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50vh;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#inside-container {
  display: block;
  width: 2400px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

.items {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}

#item1 {
  background: green;
}

#item2 {
  background: red;
}

#item3 {
  background: blue;
}

#item4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.carousel-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.data-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 31%;
  left: 19%;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: large;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div id="outside-container">
    <div id="inside-container" class="cf">
      <div class="items" id="item1">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{rio_de_janeiro.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{rio_de_janeiro.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{rio_de_janeiro.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{rio_de_janeiro.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items active" id="item2">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{new_york.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{new_york.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{new_york.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{new_york.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{new_york.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item3">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{london.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{london.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{london.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{london.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{london.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
      <div class="items" id="item4">
        <div class="data-div invisible">
          <ul>
            <li><b>{{sidney.city}}</b> </li>
            <li>{{sidney.weather.description}}</li>
            <!-- <img src="{{sidney.weather.icon}}" alt=""> -->
            <li>{{sidney.main.temperature}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="{% static 'weather/images/cities/' %}{{sidney.city_capitalized}}.jpg" class="carousel-img">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I don't think I've explained myself good enough. I know how to add/remove classes with JS/JQ. What I'm haveing trouble with is to trace the current "slide" (items in the code) of my carousel, in order to remove the "invisible" class to the "data-div" that is shown in the frame